# Framework will not archive with configuration named "Release"

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration

I have the weirdest problem right now…
My team used to have unconventional configuration names in Xcode. I am working to introduce xcconfig files and reintroduce the default `Debug` and `Release` configurations.

We have a framework that *will* not archive when using the `Release` config, but simply renaming the config to `Release2` makes everything work. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Idea: After cleaning Derived Data without success, I would use the console to search the complete content of your project folder for "Release2" and assume you can than fix the issue by replacing occurrences of "Release2" with "Release".